# Function returning result before fulfilling all the promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am trying to return an array of objects after retrieving data from two separate collections in mongodb.

Since two collections are connected through foreign key, I am trying to do some *async await* operation to get data one after another and return the result after fulfilling all promises.

But the *getCommentDetails* function is returning an empty array before running the forEach loop.

```
const getCommentDetails = async (id) => {
  const commentDetails = [];

  const comments = await commentsCollection
    .find({ complain_id: id })
    .toArray();

  comments.forEach(async (comment) => {
    const user = await usersCollection.findOne({
      _id: ObjectId(comment.user_id),
    });

    commentDetails.push({
      _id: comment._id,
      complainId: comment.complain_id,
      userId: comment.user_id,
      comment: comment.comment,
      name: user.name,
      date: comment.createdAt,
    });
  });

  return commentDetails;// it returns []
};


const getComments = async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    const data = await getCommentDetails(id);
    return res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: What are trying to do with `res.json(data)`? The `.json()` method of a thenable object returned from `fetch()` does not accept any arguments.

Comment: I am returning the data in front end with `res.json(data)` and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forEach` method is firing off multiple asynchronous executions, so the `getCommentDetails` function returns undefined before all those executions end.

Please, use `for...of` instead.

Try the following JavaScript code instead:

```
const getCommentDetails = async (id) => {
  const commentDetails = [];

  const comments = await commentsCollection
    .find({ complain_id: id })
    .toArray();

  for (const comment of comments) {
    const user = await usersCollection.findOne({
      _id: ObjectId(comment.user_id),
    });

    commentDetails.push({
      _id: comment._id,
      complainId: comment.complain_id,
      userId: comment.user_id,
      comment: comment.comment,
      name: user.name,
      date: comment.createdAt,
    });
  }

  return commentDetails;// it returns []
};


const getComments = async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    const data = await getCommentDetails(id);
    return res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't await promises in a `forEach` like that. You need to use `Promise.all`, which will execute the promises in paralell:

```
// ...

const commentDetails = await Promise.all(comments.map(async (comment) => {
    const user = await usersCollection.findOne({
      _id: ObjectId(comment.user_id),
    });

    return {
      _id: comment._id,
      complainId: comment.complain_id,
      userId: comment.user_id,
      comment: comment.comment,
      name: user.name,
      date: comment.createdAt,
    };
  }));

 return commentDetails;
```

If you need to do the promises serially, you need a `for ... of` loop instead.